# What am I doing wrong in this multipart request?

Tags: java, api, multipartform-data, micronaut, freshdesk

I am trying to send a multipart request to freshdesk api and testing on postman. The server is returning

```
{
    "message": "Internal Server Error: Bad Request"
}
```

Code is listed below,

```
@Controller("/freshdesk")
public class FreshdeskController {

    @Client("/")
    @Inject
    public RxHttpClient httpClient;

    @Post(value = "/ticket/create/attach", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public List addTicketwAttachment(@Body @Part CompletedFileUpload file,
                                         @Body @Part String email,
                                         @Body @Part String subject,
                                         @Body @Part String description) throws IOException {


        File targetFile = new File("src/main/resources/targetFile.png");
        OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);
        outStream.write(file.getBytes());

        MultipartBody requestBody = MultipartBody.builder()
                .addPart("attachments[]", targetFile.getName(), MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_TYPE, targetFile)
                .addPart("email", email)
                .addPart("subject", subject)
                .addPart("description", description)
                .build() ;

        Flowable<HttpResponse<List>> call = httpClient.exchange(
                HttpRequest.POST("https://mayankaug6.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets", requestBody)
                        .header("Authorization", apiKey)
                        .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE),
                List.class
        );
        HttpResponse<List> response = call.blockingFirst();


        return response.body();
    }
}
```

Error shown upon executing the code,

```
ERROR i.m.h.s.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler - Unexpected error occurred: Bad Request
io.micronaut.http.client.exceptions.HttpClientResponseException: Bad Request
        at io.micronaut.http.client.DefaultHttpClient$10.channelRead0(DefaultHttpClient.java:1799)
        at io.micronaut.http.client.DefaultHttpClient$10.channelRead0(DefaultHttpClient.java:1739)
        at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:438)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:328)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:302)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:253)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:287)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1475)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1224)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1271)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:505)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:444)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:283)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1421)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:930)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:697)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:632)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:549)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:511)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:918)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.micronaut.http.context.ServerRequestContext.with(ServerRequestContext.java:52)
        at io.micronaut.http.context.ServerRequestContext.lambda$instrument$0(ServerRequestContext.java:68)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have already enabled annotation processing. Also, right now I have multiple arguments for fetching different parts. Is there any way to fetch all of the parts using one single argument?

Comment: Could you please provide complete error trace?

Comment: @Govind i solved it. My code is allright, All i missed was two parameters/parts. it was not mentioned anywhere in freshdesk api. But my second question is still open, How can i fetch all the parts using on single argument.

Comment: Use `addTicketwAttachment (@Body MultipartBody multipartBody)` and access all variables. You need change the way you consume this method from frontend or another java class.

Comment: @Govind you are saying that i need to create another method/class which fetches the value from postman, bind all the parts to multipartbody and then passes it to addTicketwAttachment. btw i have made a seperate thread regarding this issue. If u can, please elaborate ur response over there (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62740606/micronaut-how-can-i-fetch-all-the-parts-for-multipart-request-using-a-single-a)